# Spring Boot application is failing to start with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I see the below error in logs

```
2019-03-20 18:53:28.846 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.848 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.852 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilterCustomizer)
```

**From logs**

```
    2019-03-20 18:53:28.744 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Unsupported type public org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources()
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.744 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Unsupported type public org.apache.catalina.LifecycleState org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getState()
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.744 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Unsupported type public java.net.URL[] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getURLs()
m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute clearReferencesStopTimerThreads public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getClearReferencesStopTimerThreads() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setClearReferencesStopTimerThreads(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute clearReferencesRmiTargets public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getClearReferencesRmiTargets() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setClearReferencesRmiTargets(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getClearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setClearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute serviceName public java.lang.String org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getServiceName() null
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute defaultAssertionStatus null public void java.lang.ClassLoader.setDefaultAssertionStatus(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute delegate public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getDelegate() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setDelegate(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute webappName public java.lang.String org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getWebappName() null
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute clearReferencesLogFactoryRelease public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getClearReferencesLogFactoryRelease() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setClearReferencesLogFactoryRelease(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute stateName public java.lang.String org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getStateName() null
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Introspected attribute clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread public boolean org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getClearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread() public void org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.setClearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread(boolean)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.m.MbeansDescriptorsIntrospectionSource : Setting name: org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             :  name = Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.747 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : ObjectName = Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
          context: ROOT
          delegate: true
        ----------> Parent Classloader:
        sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
         Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : name = Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Send create notification of object Tomcat:context=/,host=localhost,type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : JMX.mbean.registered Tomcat:type=TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesRmiTargets=true)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopThreads=false)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopTimerThreads=false)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread=true)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.748 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=true)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.782 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Managed= Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.782 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             :  name = Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : ObjectName = Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[].StandardWrapper[default] Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : name = Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Send create notification of object Tomcat:J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none,WebModule=//localhost/,j2eeType=Servlet,name=default
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : JMX.mbean.registered Tomcat:j2eeType=Servlet,WebModule=//localhost/,name=default,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Managed= Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             :  name = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : ObjectName = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[] Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : name = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Send create notification of object Tomcat:context=/,host=localhost,name=NonLoginAuthenticator,type=Valve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.783 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : JMX.mbean.registered Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=NonLoginAuthenticator
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.784 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : No SingleSignOn Valve is present
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Managed= Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             :  name = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : ObjectName = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[] Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : name = Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Send create notification of object Tomcat:context=/,host=localhost,name=StandardContextValve,type=Valve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : JMX.mbean.registered Tomcat:type=Valve,host=localhost,context=/,name=StandardContextValve
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.785 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : No manager found. Checking if cluster manager should be used. Cluster configured: [false], Application distributable: [false]
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.791 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Configured a manager of class [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager]
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Managed= Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             :  name = Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : ObjectName = Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean   : preRegister org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@40b624f3 Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : name = Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Send create notification of object Tomcat:context=/,host=localhost,type=NamingResources
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.792 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : JMX.mbean.registered Tomcat:type=NamingResources,host=localhost,context=/
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.801 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResourceAsStream(META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.801 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.801 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Searching local repositories
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.802 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Resource not found, returning null
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.804  INFO 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.832 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.832 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.833 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.833 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.839 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.839 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.840 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.840 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.842 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.842 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.846 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.848 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.852 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.852 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.853 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.853 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.854 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.854 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.858 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.858 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.863 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.core.OrderedCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.863 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.core.OrderedCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.864 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.864 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.865 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(javax.servlet.FilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.865 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(javax.servlet.FilterCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.866 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.866 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.867 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.867 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.867 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.867 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.869 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.869 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.871 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.871 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.875 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapableCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.876 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapableCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.878 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.878 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.881 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.881 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAwareCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.883 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.883 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.884 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.884 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.885 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.885 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.885 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.885 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBeanCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.886 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.886 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.894 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.895 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.895 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.895 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.897 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfigurationCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.897 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfigurationCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.898 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.898 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.899 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2d0d8e7Customizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.899 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2d0d8e7Customizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.900 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.900 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.903 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$EnhancedConfigurationCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.904 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$EnhancedConfigurationCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.904 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.904 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Passing on ClassNotFoundException
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.935 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findClass(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.936 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :       findClassInternal(java.lang.ObjectCustomizer)
        2019-03-20 18:53:28.936 DEBUG 6522 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Returning ClassNotFoundException
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <bigtable.version>1.9.0</bigtable.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <postgres.version>42.2.5</postgres.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
                <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x</artifactId>
                <version>${bigtable.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- adding for error-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Comment: Remove all `org.springframework` dependencies, those are already included in thte `spring-boot-starter-web` part. Use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead of the current Spring Security dependency and use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` instead of `spring-jdbc`.